# Can you help me identify this LEGO set? Sand green car with crumpled hood and engine on back?

Tags: set-identification

Can you please help me identify this LEGO set?

[image]

Answer (score 7):

This vehicle is part of [10669-1: Turtle Lair](https://brickset.com/sets/10669-1/Turtle-Lair)

[image]